# Slick2d | TextField character passing

Tags: java, keylistener, slick2d

### The problem:

I wrote some GUI stuff (a button) for my game. But Im stuck at creating the TextField, becouse the KeyListener is not working. I tried to implement the KeyListener but did not work. 
What should I do?

**Links:**

> [***The game (finished)***](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhvf5vbqj25sgyw/game.jar)

**The code:**

```
public class TextField extends GUI implements KeyListener {
    private boolean focused = false;
    private String text = "";

    public TextField(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public boolean isFocused() {
        return focused;
    }

    public void setFocused(boolean focused) {
        this.focused = focused;
    }

    public void append(String text) {
        this.text = this.text + text;
    }

    public void delete() {
        if (text.length() > 0) {
            text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) {
        if (!focused) {
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.orange);
        }
        g.fillRect(x - width / 2, y - height / 2, width, height);

        g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
        g.fillRect(x - width / 2 + 5, y - height / 2 + 5, width - 10, height - 10);

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString(text, x - g.getFont().getWidth(text) / 2, y - g.getFont().getHeight(text) / 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void setInput(Input input) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAcceptingInput() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void inputEnded() {
    }

    @Override
    public void inputStarted() {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(int i, char c) {
        System.out.println("This is not working");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(int i, char c) {
    }
}
```

**This is how I create a TextField:**

```
ipField = new TextField(width / 2, height / 2 - 60, 200, 50);
ipField.add(new ActionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void pressed() {
        ipField.setFocused(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void hover() {
    }

    @Override
    public void notHover() {
        if (input.isMousePressed(0)) {
            ipField.setFocused(false);
        }
    }
});
guiManager.add(ipField);
```

**I found out, I can use a built in TextField for this:*

```
org.newdawn.slick.gui.TextField
```

Comment: Use a `DocumentListener` cause changes can happen to the text via copy, cut and paste along with key input :)

Comment: DocumentListener? It gaves me 3 methods, but how can I use it?

Comment: Anyways, that not solve my main problem

Comment: My friend, your syntax for keyListener methods are wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to JavaDoc, `KeyListener` methods have the following syntax:

`void  keyPressed(KeyEvent e)`
 `void  keyReleased(KeyEvent e)`
 `void  keyTyped(KeyEvent e)`

Going over your code, your syntax are:
`public void keyPressed(int i, char c)`
`public void keyReleased(int i, char c)`

This will be flagged as an error at compilation time.

Also, you should, *ideally*, create a separate handler class for your events.
`TextField` is the object that will *generate* the event and there must be someone to listen to it. You need to specify who will listen by calling the `addKeyListener()` method and passing the handler class' object as an argument.

*PS: Switch to Swing. Use JTextField instead*

Refer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html
Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html
Event delegation model: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_delegation_event_model_in_java
Advantages of swing: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/112482/advantage-of-using-swing-over-awt

Comment: Im using the slick2d's KeyListener (org.newdawn.slick), not the atw's KeyListener. Otherwise, I tried that too but nothing happened

Comment: It would be very hard, to use swing in slick2d. There are some UI libraries such as TWL, but I'd like to write my own.